# How to count 365 days from current system date to past and future date and fetch the data accordingly using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data according to date which is expired.

I have database like this

`Equipment`     `Purchase Date`     `Expiry Date`

`Laptop`        `2015-07-15`        `2016-07-15`
`Mobile`        `2012-07-15`        `2013-07-15`
`Desktop`        `2011-07-15`        `2012-07-15`

Now I want to fetch data which is expired, if the purchase date lies under 365 days from current date that means Equipment not expired, else expired. So, How to fetch data data which is expired and How to fetch data data which is not expired.

I managed to count date and print the condition like this.

```
 $purchasedate = strtotime ($row['purchasedate']);
 $todayDate = strtotime (date("j-m-Y"));
 $timeDiff = abs($todayDate - $supplydate1);
 $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;
 $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

 if ($numberDays > 365)
 {
     $expiry = 'Warranty Expired';
 } else {

     $expiry = 'Under Warranty';
     }
```

But i only want to fetch data which is expired, and which is not expired.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL date arithmetic.

```
SELECT equipment,
       CASE WHEN expiryDate > CURDATE() THEN 'Current'
                                         ELSE 'Expired' END
  FROM table
```

If you want to display only the expired rows, append this `WHERE` clause to your query.

```
 WHERE expiryDate <= CURDATE()
```

There are all sorts of cool things you can do with date arithmetic. For example, to find all the rows expiring between now and two months from now, use this `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE expiryDate > CURDATE()
  AND expiryDate <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

Similarly, if you want to see rows where the purchase date is a year ago or more, you can do this.

```
WHERE purchaseDate <= CURDATE() 1 INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

This SQL data arithmetic allows you to escape the need to count days or months; it knows the necessary calendar details.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting all the data, I want data which is expired. @Ollie Jones

Comment: Please see my edit. Excuse me, I misunderstood your question.